# Authentication via .net web api 2 from client side - plain text visible credentials

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, authentication, encryption

I have a legacy database system I cannot change which stores (very simply) hashed passwords.  It's not a mega-sensitive system so I'm not too concerned about the world's greatest security system, however...

I have a client-side modal login window that accepts username and password then calls a Web Api method to authenticate against the database. In the server-side code, it uses MD5 to hash the password and uses that to match the user/pass record on the SQL database.

It all works fine, but I'm concerned that the developer tools in chrome show that (obviously) the XHR request is unencrypted and it shows, for example, `http://localhost:50683/api/mycontroller/Login/?usr=fred&pass=bloggs`.  It could be argued this is fine as the user is on their own machine and is only seeing what they typed in, but when deployed internally this will be on an intranet and sometimes the users share computers so one (with sufficient knowledge) could look at network tab XHR history and see another user's password.

As a simple low-tech workaround, I thought of doing some basic encryption on the client side before sending the credentials, then unencrypting/re-encrypting them on the server before doing the authentication request but (I'm not expert, as you'll realise!) wouldn't that mean having to have the encryption salt in plain view on the client side too, therefore rendering it largely pointless?

How do other systems cope with obfuscating the credentials from the client side in this kind of scenario?  Am I worrying over nothing here?  I just don't like seeing plain text in my XHR history!

Comment: This may be solved with asymmetric encryption by sending the public key to the client. This will of course not be secure against a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: Any examples/links to explain this more please Artjom?

Comment: This problem is solved with a server certificate and requiring HTTPS communication between the client app and the api -- no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I realise people are trying to help, but suggesting answers via comments that are not really answering the question but instead saying, "you should do it like this instead..." aren't always *that* helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the javascript library here: http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/ to hash the password before calling the web service.

Yes, I realise that this is not massively secure, but refer to my original question, where I say: "It's not a mega-sensitive system so I'm not too concerned about the world's greatest security system".

If I needed more security, then I would look to https and/or Oauth or whatever, but for just wanting to obfuscate the password so that members of staff internally don't see the plain text password of a colleague, that works really well for me and may be of use to others.